# How write *.sh to mv and run files

Tags: scripts

I have two config.yml files but don't want to use cron or type them manually. I want to name them file1.bak and file2.bak. When I'm in the mood to run them I want to type something like ./call.sh or ./call2.sh
The script will automatically have root privelege and change file1.bak to config.yml and run it. then it will change it back to file1.bak. I want no permanent config.yml because I use two or three separate files depending on what I want them to do.
Would appreciate any help. For reference this is a config.yml file for flexget. I should combine everything but I like separate files to find errors easier.
ray

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash 
mv /full_PATH/file1.bak config.yml
mv /full_PATH/file2.bak config2.yml 
sudo ./config.yml
```

This should work..save this file with say "test.sh" and them in terminal type ./test.sh

Answer (score 1):

Any unix user should have the Advanced Bash Scripting Guide as a bookmark, this I would say is the bible when it comes to shell scripting and I constantly use it as a reference:

http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/

Without knowing what flexget is and how config.yml is used in this context, I would suggest something in the line of:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
FILE=$1
CONFIG_PATH="/home/user/yml"
CONFIG_FILE="$CONFIG_PATH/file$FILE.bak"

if [ ! -e $CONFIG_FILE ]
then
    echo "Sorry, $CONFIG_FILE does not exist"
    exit 1
fi

cp $CONFIG_FILE /home/user/config.yml
sudo /home/user/config.yml
rm /home/user/config.yml
```

If you then want to use file2.bak, you would add 2 as a parameter to the script:

```
./call.sh 2
```

Replace 2 with 1 if you want to use file1.bak.